# AWS EC2 ftp sftp login not working after restart

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ftp

I have an AWS EC2 ubuntu server, which was working well two days back.
I had to restart the server after some updates and after that i found that the FTP and SFTP is not getting connected.

I checked the security groups and nothing is changed. 
When trying to connect vuia SSH or FTP it shows the message "Connection refused"

How could i fix this issue?

thank you

Comment: Is your FTP service running? It may not be set to start at launch.

Comment: Thank You datasage, the issue is, as long as we are not able to login to SSH, we cannot restart any service.

Comment: is your instance passing the status checks?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the SFTP connection would stop working on an EC2 instance if I placed custom commands in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile.  After moving the custom lines from .bashrc to .bash_profile, the SFTP browser (on MobaXterm) fired right up after exiting and logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar problem and I suposse that probably the problem is not really related with AWS EC2 directly but to the protocol SSH and SFTP. Maybe the problem is due to some updates in files as .bashrc or similar that calls echo or produces an output. According to an old [openssh documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114130008/http://www.openssh.com:80/faq.html#2.9), if those files produces outputs to stdout the sftp client will be confuse and it will close the conection.

So in those file shouldn't be any echo command, but some variable definitions of commands without output to stdout will be good.

To test if your connection to EC2 instance produces any output to stdout you can run this command. If this returns something, maybe it will cause problems to sftp connections but it will work fine with ssh.

```
ssh -i <path_to_pem_file> <user>@<ip_ec2_instance> /usr/bin/true
```

If this is the case a better aproximation is add those commands with outputs to .bash_profile instead of .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is Amazon linux environment and MobaXterm, but file upload did not work.

I installed NVM and set the node 18 version as the default, but the following error message occurred and the node command was not available.

node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v18.3.0` to unset it.

So I added the "nvm use 16" line to .bashrc, which is why the file was not uploaded.

When I delete the line, the file uploads well.

Finally, the problem was solved by setting the default version of the node with the command below.

nvm alias default 16.15.1